How much weight can my garage attic hold?
I have an early 2000's house with an attached 2-car garage and wanted to get some more attic space, the garage is fully drywalled including the ceiling but is not insulated. I wanted to cut an opening into the drywall and be able to store some christmas lights and some boxes etc. The bottom chords, are about 20' long and run parallel to the garage door. The bottom chords look like they are 2x10, maybe 2x12, i forgot to bring a tape measure with me when i went up. They are however spaced 18" apart from another. Although an 18" opening sounds pretty small too so i was actually planning on moving one of the chords over a few inches.
Please let me know what yall think

Any supporting walls under it?  If not, probably a lot less than you want.  Maybe only walking, a few pounds of storage.

No walls, just a regular open 2 car garage
